# Emails footer.html not in en_US localization (multistore)

Tags: email, localisation, footer, magento1.9.2.4

I think since an update to 1.9.2.4, I have problems with the email footer (`/app/locale/en_US/template/email/html/footer.html`). In my default-shop in german (de_DE) the content of footer.html is shown, in other stores with en_US, not. The integration is the same `{{template config_path="design/email/footer"}}`, the content nearly (only translated).

What could be the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Check the design folder for any xml that may be changing where the template is loaded. Sometimes it's a file like app/design/front end/custom_theme_name/default/layout/local.xml or may be another xml 
If the layout instructions were set here to point to a different template that may explain why it works for one theme and not another.